# R import XML from Graphpad Prism

Tags: xml, r

I am trying to import raw data from Graphpad Prism .pzfx files, which in principle are .xml files. I took out most of the prism specific stuff and left just the part I am interested in.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GraphPadPrismFile xmlns="http://graphpad.com/prism/Prism.htm" PrismXMLVersion="5.00">
  <TableSequence Selected="1">
    <Ref ID="Table0" Selected="1"/>
  </TableSequence>
  <Table ID="Table0" XFormat="error" YFormat="replicates" Replicates="1" TableType="XY" EVFormat="AsteriskAfterNumber">
    <Title>Data 1</Title>
    <XColumn Width="162" Decimals="0" Subcolumns="1">
      <Title>X</Title>
      <Subcolumn>
        <d>1</d>
        <d>2</d>
        <d>3</d>
        <d>4</d>
        <d>5</d>
      </Subcolumn>
    </XColumn>
    <YColumn Width="81" Decimals="4" Subcolumns="1">
      <Title>ML</Title>
      <Subcolumn>
        <d>120</d>
        <d>100</d>
        <d>5</d>
        <d>0</d>
        <d>1.5</d>
      </Subcolumn>
    </YColumn>
    <YColumn Width="81" Decimals="4" Subcolumns="1">
      <Title>MH</Title>
      <Subcolumn>
        <d>10</d>
        <d>560</d>
        <d>665</d>
        <d>40</d>
        <d>31.5</d>
      </Subcolumn>
    </YColumn>
    <YColumn Width="81" Decimals="6" Subcolumns="1">
      <Title>MH2</Title>
      <Subcolumn>
        <d>1.20</d>
        <d>100</d>
        <d>5</d>
        <d>0</d>
        <d>1.5</d>
      </Subcolumn>
    </YColumn>
    <YColumn Width="81" Decimals="6" Subcolumns="1">
      <Title>MH1</Title>
      <Subcolumn>
        <d>120</d>
        <d>100</d>
        <d>5</d>
        <d>0</d>
        <d>1.5</d>
      </Subcolumn>
    </YColumn>
  </Table>
</GraphPadPrismFile>
```

To my understanding I have a Node Table which again has XColumn, YColumn nodes, which have Title and then have Subcolumn nodes. Those contain my raw data I would like to convert into a R-data.frame.

So far I have managed to import one YColumn: (file is the path to the one above)

```
xData <- xmlParse(file)
xData.rt <- xmlRoot(xData)
xmlToDataFrame(xData.rt[["Table"]][["YColumn"]][["Subcolumn"]])
```

This gives me the first YColumn as a data.frame:

```
  text
1  120
2  100
3    5
4    0
5  1.5
```

Is there a (maybe also simpler?) way to import all X and Y Colums into one data.frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some ideas...

This finds all the `XColumn` and `YColumn` nodes:

```
columns = xpathSApply(xData,"//ns:XColumn|//ns:YColumn",
             namespaces=c(ns="http://graphpad.com/prism/Prism.htm"))
```

Then, given one of those, this gets the title and the values:

```
> xpathSApply(columns[[2]],".//ns:Title",
    namespaces=c(ns="http://graphpad.com/prism/Prism.htm"),xmlValue)
[1] "ML"
> xpathSApply(columns[[2]],".//ns:d",
    namespaces=c(ns="http://graphpad.com/prism/Prism.htm"),xmlValue)
[1] "120" "100" "5"   "0"   "1.5"
```

You can tell if something is an `XColumn` or a `YColumn` by checking its `xmlName`:

```
> xmlName(columns[[1]])
[1] "XColumn"
> xmlName(columns[[2]])
[1] "YColumn"
```

That's probably enough construction kit pieces. Loop over `columns` and stack the values up with `cbind` probably...

Obviously the character-based numbers need converting with `as.numeric`, and I'm not exactly sure how you want to combine the `XColumn` and `YColumn` values given there's one fewer `XColumn` value...

Comment: great! That way I should be able to construct a data.frame. I just forgot a row in the XColumn, so I don't need to worry about that...

Answer (score 1):

Update: the library is also on CRAN and can be installed by:

```
install.packages("pzfx")
```

tl;dr: After studying the XML structure of pzfx files I wrote a package [here](https://github.com/Yue-Jiang/pzfx) and a blog post [here](https://yuejiang.org/2018/08/02/pzfx/). Briefly,

```
devtools::install_github("Yue-Jiang/pzfx")
library(pzfx)
pzfx_tables("/path/to/my/pzfx/file") # list tables in a .pzfx file
df <- read_pzfx("/path/to/my/pzfx/file", 1) # read first table
df <- read_pzfx("/path/to/my/pzfx/file", "Table Name") # read table by name
```

A couple things I noticed when trying to parse the prsim XML:

1. Prism allows users to have subcolumns but they can mean different things, and this is specified as a `YFormat` attribute of the table. For instance, `replicates` means the subcolumns are replicates, while `SDN` means the subcolumns are mean, sd and number of observations. The `pzfx` package tries to infer the subcolumn types by looking at `YFormat` and append appropriate suffixes to the column names.
2. Prism allows users to strike out certain cells from the table. This is specified by a `Excluded` attribute of the subcolumn. When reading the table, one needs to decide what to do about these excluded values. The `pzfx` package allows the user to either keep, exclude or keeping the "*" as is in the prsim file (which makes all columns of type `character`).

Hopefully this is somewhat useful if someone needs to do something similar. Issue reports are welcome on github.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, but as the other reviewers noted, a link to the solution isn't a valid answer. Obviously, there's no room to post your whole package, but I hope you'll spend a little time explaining how you did this so that even if those links break someday, a future visitor could recreate your solution. Thanks again!